# ORA-01180 when restoring the database

Tags: oracle, rman

I get the following error message when trying to restore the database from backup using RMAN.

```
rman target /

RMAN> set dbid=130474031
RMAN> configure device type 'sbt_tape' clear;
RMAN> startup nomount;
RMAN> restore controlfile from autobackup;
RMAN> sql 'alter database mount';
RMAN> restore database;

Starting restore at 22-DEC-15
using channel ORA_DISK_1

creating datafile fno=1 name=/opt/oracle/oradata/prod/system01.dbf
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at 12/22/2015 12:47:01
ORA-01180: can not create datafile 1
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/opt/oracle/oradata/prod/system01.dbf'
RMAN>
```

**EDIT**

```
RMAN> restore database;

Starting restore at 22-DEC-15
using channel ORA_DISK_1

creating datafile fno=1 name=/opt/oracle/oradata/prod/system01.dbf
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at 12/22/2015 14:22:01
ORA-01180: can not create datafile 1
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/opt/oracle/oradata/prod/system01.dbf'

RMAN> exit


Recovery Manager complete.
[oracle@DR-Corebank ~]$ id
uid=501(oracle) gid=501(oinstall) groups=501(oinstall),502(dba)
[oracle@DR-Corebank ~]$ cd /opt/oracle/oradata/prod/
[oracle@DR-Corebank prod]$ touch aaa
[oracle@DR-Corebank prod]$ ls -ltr
total 875772
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 298631168 Dec 22 14:22 control03.ctl
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 298631168 Dec 22 14:22 control02.ctl
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 298631168 Dec 22 14:22 control01.ctl
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall         0 Dec 22 14:22 aaa
[oracle@DR-Corebank prod]$ pwd
/opt/oracle/oradata/prod
[oracle@DR-Corebank prod]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/cciss/c0d0p3     1.1T  163G  850G  17% /
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1     244M   18M  213M   8% /boot
tmpfs                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/mpath0    493G  248M  467G   1% /opt/oracle2/u002
```

Comment: Do you have a backup of datafile 1? `list backup of datafile 1;` Is the database incarnation set correctly? `list incarnation;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*<sub>Community Wiki answer from a self-answer originally edited into the question (and based on a comment by [Balazs Papp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/28019/balazs-papp)).</sub>*

I forgot an incarnation:

```
RMAN> list incarnation;

List of Database Incarnations
DB Key  Inc Key DB Name  DB ID            STATUS  Reset SCN  Reset Time
------- ------- -------- ---------------- --- ---------- ----------
1       1       PROD     130474031        PARENT  1          10-MAY-10
2       2       PROD     130474031        PARENT  195833299  21-OCT-10
3       3       PROD     130474031        PARENT  3655020271 06-OCT-12
4       4       PROD     130474031        PARENT  3655121615 08-OCT-12
5       5       PROD     130474031        CURRENT 5588371557 19-OCT-14

RMAN> reset database to incarnation 4;

database reset to incarnation 4

RMAN> restore database;

Starting restore at 22-DEC-15
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: sid=10993 devtype=DISK

creating datafile fno=3 name=/opt/oracle/oradata/prod/sysaux01.dbf
creating datafile fno=4 name=/opt/oracle/oradata/prod/users01.dbf
```

The problem is now solved.

Answer (score 0):

check if this directory `/opt/oracle/oradata/prod/` exist and oracle user has the needed permission on this directory

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to crosscheck backup before the restore succeeded. Somehow its status was `EXPIRED`.