# Recreate Oracle Database using .BKP files?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

We have a local development database. Our customer has a production database.

Both databases started the same - same tablespaces, tables, users, schemas, indexes, views, etc.

Months went by. They put data in their database. We put different data in our database. But all the structure stuff should be the same. The OS and database software is also the same.

We want to bring the two databases into sync, so that our development database has all the data from their production database.

They've provided us with 76 .BKP files. Those files are now sitting on a drive connected to the server that hosts our development database. How do we actually get the data out of these files and into our database? This is all oracle 12c, if that's important.

Looking online I saw people talking about `rman`. I tried starting it up like this:

```
$ rman target=/
```

It appears to have properly connected to the existing database.

All of the `.BKP` files are located in `/u01/dumpfilesgohere`. In Oracle SQL Developer, under the SYS account for the database, there's a directory named `IMPORT_FILES` for that, thus why I thought it would be a good place to put the files.

But when I run `SHOW ALL;` in `rman`, it doesn't show that directory anywhere:

```
RMAN> SHOW ALL;

using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name ECLS are:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1; # default
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE MAXSETSIZE TO UNLIMITED; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES128'; # default
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'BASIC' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE ; # default
CONFIGURE RMAN OUTPUT TO KEEP FOR 7 DAYS; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO NONE; # default
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/dbs/snapcf_ECLS.f'; # default
```

Edit: Here's the list of names of files I was provided with:

```
 9 files matching: O1_MF_ANNNN_TAG20161218T020128_D5CV????_.BKP
 3 files matching: O1_MF_ANNNN_TAG20161218T042945_D5D45???_.BKP
63 files matching: O1_MF_NNND0_TAG20161218T021024_D5??????_.BKP
 1 unique file:    O1_MF_S_930889816_D5D475W3_.BKP
```

Edit #2: After trying to get the DBID and DB Name of the backup files by attempting to catalog them with RMAN, I decided to try changing the DBID and DB Name by following [this article](https://www.pythian.com/blog/how-to-choose-your-oracle-database-id-dbid/). The actual steps I did are below:

1. `$ sqlplus / as sysdba`
2. `SQL> shutdown immediate`
3. `SQL> startup open read only`
4. `SQL> @/u01/change_dbid.sql` This file has all the code of section 2 and 3 from the article above. It seems to have run successfully on my server, despite the instructions being written for Oracle 11 and me using Oracle 12c.
5. `SQL> create pfile from spfile;`
6. I made a copy of the file at /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/dbs/initOLDNAME.ora with OLDNAME changed to match the name from the backup, and I changed the line `*.db_name='OLDNAME'` to have the name from the backup. I changed nothing else about the file.
7. `SQL> shutdown immediate`
8. `SQL> startup mount pfile=initNEWNAME.ora`
9. `SQL> alter database open resetlogs;`
10. `SQL> create spfile from pfile='initNEWNAME.ora`;
11. `SQL> startup force`
12. `SQL> exit`
13. `$ rman target=/`
14. `RMAN> catalog start with '/u01/dumpfilesgohere/';` It listed those 76 .BKP files, I told it to go, and it told me it successfully cataloged all the files.
15. `RMAN> restore database;`

Here's the output from step #15:

```
Starting restore at 26-JAN-17
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=3 device type=DISK

creating datafile file number=1 name=/u01/app/oracle/oradata/OLDNAME/system01.dbf
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at 01/26/2017 10:50:46
ORA-01180: can not create datafile 1
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/OLDNAME/system01.dbf'
```

I'm stuck again - I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Maybe changing the DB ID and name was a mistake...

Comment: Are these RMAN backups or datapump exports ? Do you have any backup logs accompanying those .BKP files ?

Comment: @A_V - I believe these are RMAN backups. Historically, we've copied data between our environments by using datapumps, but it would take several days. They told us that they wanted to use these files going forward because it only takes them hours instead of days to produce them.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124327/ora-01180-when-restoring-the-database

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. You just need to catalog the files so that `rman` is aware of them.

At a `rman` prompt:

```
CATALOG START WITH '/u01/dumpfilesgohere/';
```

(the trailing slash is important).

Comment: Okay - thank you for that. Now I'm hitting this issue - it's not cataloging any of the files. For every file, it spat out this error message: `RMAN-07518: Reason: Foreign database file DBID: 1345519754  Database Name: COOVZP`. How can I fix this? If possible, I'd rather not change our database SID... we already have dozens of machines successfully connecting to the database and I don't want to have to go through and change them all. I'm fine with changing the DBID... I don't think that's used anywhere.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare You need to restore the controlfile first. Provided the production environment is taking a control file autobackup, have them send you that backup (they may have already sent you that piece, or the controlfile backup could have been included with the database backup), then: RMAN> shutdown immediate; startup nomount; restore controlfile from '<full path of controlfile backup>'; alter database mount; catalog start with... ;

Comment: @KrisJohnston - I edited my question to include the names of all the files I was provided with at the end. Do you think any of those might be the control file?

Comment: @KrisJohnston - Also, what would restoring the controlfile actually do? Would that change the SID of the database?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare There is no way to tell from the filenames.  If you can get the other team to do a RMAN> show all; from the production environment, that will tell you how the CF autobackup is named: from the show all line: CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT...  The CF autobackup is usually pretty small, so odds are, it would be the smallest file.  If the CF backup is part of the database backup, it may be included in the last file (based on the last write date/time).

Comment: Restoring the controlfile to your dev database won't change the SID, but it will change the database name (if they are different). It will also set the paths to all of the data files, redo log files... You "may" have to : RMAN> set dbid 1345519754; restore controlfile from...; but I would try the restore controlfile first and see if that works.

Comment: @KrisJohnston - I've updated my question (see Update #2) to show everything I've tried since. I'm stuck again.